# Gradient of a Straight Line

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:

**Find the value of $a$ if the gradient joining the points $(-2,a)$ to $(a + 1, -10)$ is $-2$.**

At first I tried plotting some of the values given into the equation $y = mx + c$.

For $(-2,a)$

$y = -2(-2) + C$

For $(a + 1, -10)$

$-10 = -2(a + 1) + C$

I know to find the $Y$ intercept (represented by $C$) I need to do $(y^1 - y^2/x^1 - x^2)$ but then I don't really know how to work out all the $y$ and $x$ values to use this $Y$ intercept equation.

Thanks for your help. Please use easy terms if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said:
$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=-2=\frac{-10-a}{a+1-(-2)}\Longrightarrow -2(a+3)=-10-a\\ \Longrightarrow a=4.$$

If you have

$$\frac{-10-a}{a+3}=-2,\tag{1}$$
it means that both quantities $\frac{-10-a}{a+3}$ and $-2$ are the same. So if you for instance sum $1$ to each side you end up with 
$$\frac{-10-a}{a+3}+1=-1,$$
and the equality still holds, both quantities are equal.

Also if you multiply each side in equation $(1)$ by $a+3$ the quantities will be equal as well!:
$$\frac{-10-a}{a+3}(a+3)=-2(a+3).$$ You can rewrite it as
$$(-10-a)\frac{a+3}{a+3}=-2(a+3),$$
then $\frac{a+3}{a+3}=1$.

Comment: How do you get $-2(a+3)$? I know how you got $(a+3)$ but how did you get the $-2$ part? @Vladimir Vargas

Comment: @PerfectNutter I added the answer to your question here, please reload the web site.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{ You need to solve } \\ \frac{(-10)-(a)}{(a+1)-(-2)}=-2$